# java httpRequest getRemoteAddr allways return 127.0.0.1

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, localhost, httprequest

Hello everybody and thanks for your help,

I am developing a web application using JSF and for security reasons i need to capture the user's IP when he does the log in.

I am using the following code:

```
HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
remoteAddress=request.getRemoteAddr();
```

The thing is that when I check my app logs to check the ip address it always returns 127.0.0.1.

[INFO]      07/01/2014 11:04:22 --> User xxx connected from 127.0.0.1

[INFO]      07/01/2014 11:27:43 --> User xxx connected from 127.0.0.1

For more detail:

- I am using tomcat 7
- My server works inside a debian virtual machine
- I am connecting to the server from a different pc from the one containing the VM.

I have searched in internet and read about using:

```
request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
```

But It did not solved my problem.

I am quite lost at the moment, any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: I think if you are testing from the same physical machine it will always display local IP (127.0.0.1)..

Comment: That's the thing i am not testing from the same physical machine.

Comment: Does your virtual machine have a public IP or are you using some kind of local NAT or iptables based port forwarding? Are you accessing Tomcat through an Apache frontend or calling Tomcat directly?

Comment: Both the server and my pc are in a private LAN (10.X.X.X) and i am using Apache

Comment: I forgot to say that all trafic is redirected to port 8443

Answer (score 3):

First of all, check if your http server should be forwarding the headers. You you're using nginx, this should work

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

If you're already done that, you can accomplish that using Tomcat's `RemoteIpValve`

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
           remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For"
           requestAttributesEnabled="true"
           internalProxies="127.0.0.1"  />
```

That way, when you call `request.getRemoteAddr()`, it will be providing the right information.