# How to change AWS Elastic Beanstalk to forward original ip address of request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am pretty new to all of this server/ngInx stuff, so I have an issue with forawrding the proper IP Address of a request. As of now, all of the requests are coming form the IP address 127.0.0.1 (inside the AWS). However, I need to be able to verify what is the original Ip address of a request.

As I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969513/java-httprequest-getremoteaddr-allways-return-127-0-0-1), I need to specify the following options in ngInx:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

However, I don't use custom config of the nginx on the AWS. Is there a way to only add those two lines to the default configuration of nginx on aws?

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert of nginx but you can use ebextensions (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) to solve this issue.

Basically you first need to put this new configuration within an nginx configuration file such as the below:

```
    files:
      "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Then you also need to reload the nginx by using container_commands such as below:

```
container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Should I use all of those in environment.config file under ebextensions?